# Is there any way to use os in python to go inside a directory and randomly pick k files without having to first load all file names using os.listdir?

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, computer-vision

I want to load a chunk of 64 images from inside a dataset.
I have the dataset in my working directory inside of VSCode.
VSCode crashes when I try to `os.listdir()` the contents of the directory.

The end goal is to just create a DataLoader that obtains a batch to the training function.

There is no problem in randomly picking files from inside the folder as all of them are png files.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Solve the issue with VS Code, or run your code outside the IDE. Maybe try `scandir` instead of `listdir` but that doesn't avoid enumerating the files, it just does so more efficiently.

Comment: Possible useful links: [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) and [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)

Comment: Is the directory really really really huge?

Comment: What does “I have the dataset in my working directory inside of VSCode” mean? VSCode is an IDE, you don’t put datasets in it. Also, punctuation really aids legibility, if you skip punctuation marks you make your text harder to read. If you ask for help, you have to make it as easy for others to help you as possible, which means put the damn periods at the end of your sentences.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.scandir`, it is supposed to be more efficient than `os.listdir`.

```py
import os
import random

output_dir = 'data/images'

num_images = 64

entries = os.scandir(output_dir)
filenames = [entry.name for entry in entries if entry.is_file()] 

indices = random.sample(range(len(filenames)), k=num_images)
for i in indices:
  filename = filenames[i]
  img_path = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
  # process the image
```